# Handle to last run process win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, handle

How do I get HANDLE to last run process by user? My Application will be running, has started one process using CreateProcess() or ShellExecute() , and then user comes and executes another, independent process, externally. Forget about user must be doing this and that. We are sure user will run one and only one application at exactly this point.

How do I get HANDLE to this process? I won't have its name or id or anything else. All I know is it is being run after my application started executing or rather after creating a process using one of the mentioned method above.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: (not my vote) sounds like an XY problem. Regardless of what you may assume, the fact is that on Windows many programs can start outside your direct control. E.g what if Windows Update starts?

Comment: yeah many programs can surely start. But OpenProcess() does not give handles to the processes whose user != user running this program or at lower. (Of course one can again go out of the way and get handles by some way or the other.) So in most of the "normal" cases this thing is working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Process Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs to enumerate the processes in the system, and for each use the [`GetProcessTimes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223) function to find out when the process started. Then it's just a matter of putting them into a map or otherwise sorting them to find the most recently-started one.

Comment: is Process32Next() way to go..? Or EnumProcess(), then OpenProcess() to get handle, and then get time of every process and then sort them..?

Comment: I don't think it matters really, whichever one you find easier to use should be fine. You'll have to open the process to check the process token to match against the user (as detailed on that API page I linked) in either case.